# update centos 5.9 kernel not in package list

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I wish to update my kernel. Performing `yum update kernel -y` get `No Packages marked for Update` which makes sense because there are no updates for the kernel listed in `yum list updates`.
How is it possible to update the kernel?

My current kernel is:
2.6.18-348.4.1.el5

These is my repo list:
CentOS-Debuginfo.rep
CentOS-Media.repo
CentOS-Vault.repo
city-fan.repo
epel.repo
epel-testing.repo
puppetlabs.repo
remi.repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All centos 5.x kernels are based on 2.6.18, there aren't kernels based on 3.x not 4.x codebases for centos 5.

Another important factor you should consider is that centos 5 reached EOL (End Of Life) about 1 year ago:

```
Mar 31, 2017 EOL
```

You can can confirm this on the CentOS wiki: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/EOL

This means that there are nor will be any more official updates of any kind for CentOS 5. It is past time for you to update to a newer system. Your system is completely exposed to every known vulnerability that came out in the last year.

Expanding on this:

https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product

Centos 6 has already reached the end of full-updates support on May 10th, 2017, but it will keep receiving security updates until November 30th, 2020 (EOL)

Centos 7 will have full updates till Q4 2020 and will reach EOL by June 30th, 2024

Comment: To actually answer the question though:  Yes, it is technically possible to update the Kernel.  Download the source, and get to compiling -- and good luck to you!

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think I saw a RHEL5 kernel update notification recently because spectre/meltdown. dunno if that got over to Centos5

Comment: @DopeGhoti I very much doubt it is possible to compile to an usable state 4.x kernels for a CentOS 5  box. At least not without major patching of the source code and several libraries

Comment: _Possible_?  I suspect yes.  In any way whatsoever _feasible_?  I suspect no.